# Como fazer o UITextField acompanhar o nível do teclado ao iniciar uma digitação

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

Estou com um probleminha, criei um app que possui um formulário onde tem 6 **UITextField**, mas tenho um problema ao rodar o app em um iphone4 o teclado sobrepõe alguns **UITextField** e não consigo visualizar o texto em que estou digitando, eu coloquei um **UIScrollView** para que o usuário possa possa rolar a pagina mas eu gostaria de quando o usuário focar no campo ele seja elevado ao nível do teclado como ao digitar no WhatsApp, e ao finalizar a digitação o mesmo volte a posição atual, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é bem simples de se fazer e bem comum também.

A idéia deste exemplo que vou passar é a seguinte, obter o tempo que o teclado leva para subir ou descer e obter a altura que ele vai ocupar na tela.

A primeira coisa que você precisa fazer é adicionar um handler para o evento `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`, que vai notifica-lo quando o teclado está subindo ou descendo (você vai perceber que saber se ele sobe ou desce não importa muito).

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onKeyboardChange(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil);
```

E o handler `onKeyboardChange`, que deve está disponível no escopo `self` fica assim:

```
func onKeyboardChange (notification: NSNotification )
{
    let screenBounds = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    duration = info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]!.doubleValue
    let height = screenBounds.height - keyboardFrame.origin.y

    // Daqui em diante, você pode animar suas views usando a duração
    // e o height obtidos acima
}
```

Perceba que quando você for aplicar o *height* ele já vai variar a posição vertical dos elementos que vc deseja subir ou descer na UI, ou seja, não interessa se o teclado está subindo ou descendo :)

E não se esqueça de remover o observer do evento `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` quando não for mais utiliza-lo

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
```

É isso.

Answer (score 3):

A biblioteca [TPKeyboardAvoiding](http://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) faz esse trabalho.

Após adicionar a biblioteca no projeto, modifique a classe do objeto UIScrollView que você já tinha adicionado para TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.

Comment: Muito obrigado,  Rafael.