# IOS - Impedir que o teclado esconda o Text Field?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Sempre que clico no Text Field, o teclado sobe escondendo ele na tela, gostaria de saber uma forma que fizesse o Text Field subir junto com o teclado, tentei usar um Scroll View mas não consegui.

## Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nesta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/82884/4337), tem uma dica de biblioteca que resolve esta sua questão.

Comment: Obrigado Paulo, vou tentar aqui e aviso caso tenha conseguido!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crie o delegate para os textfields e o IBOutlet para o scroll e utilize o seguinte código:

SWIFT:

```
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField : UITextField)
  {
      var pt : CGPoint
      var rc = textField.bounds
      rc = textField.convertRect(rc, toView: self.scroll)
      pt = rc.origin;
      pt.x = 0;
      pt.y -= 157;  // Ajuste de acordo com a necessidade
      self.scroll.setContentOffset(pt, animated: true)
  }
```

OBJECTIVE-C

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    CGPoint pt;
    CGRect rc = [textField bounds];
    rc = [textField convertRect:rc toView:self.scroll];
    pt = rc.origin;
    pt.x = 0;
    pt.y -= 157;  // Ajuste de acordo com a necessidade
    [self.scroll setContentOffset:pt animated:YES];    
}
```

Comment: Obrigado CCastro, vou tentar agora pela manhã e qualquer coisa lhe aviso aqui.

Comment: Consegui aqui :D
Só tive de colocar o escopo do código dentro do  -(IBAction)textField:(id)sender{}
Abraço!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a lib `TPKeyboardAvoiding`(https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding).

Basta trocar a classe da `UIScrollView` para `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`.

Comment: Quando eu add o framework e mudei a classe do scroll para TPKeyboardAvoiding ele parou de funcionar. Agora pela manhã vou criar um novo projeto, só para testar isso novamente